# Android project like .Net user controls

Tags: android

You know you can make `.ascx` pages and add it in another page as a user control. Separated code and design make your work easy to read and work.

I am working in a project that is a bit complicated; some activities going to be 5,000+ lines of code. Also, will look like it will be double-triple soon.

So I begin find a way like .Net `.ascx` pages.

Any suggestion to make my work tidy and easy?

to be clear; I am not looking some Inflating layout. I need some like activity possibly inflate in another activity. seperate onCreate seperate layout so on.

Comment: Are you using monodroid? I ask that because I have edited your question to make it clearer, and you have .Net in there which I am not sure of the context.

Comment: no I dont use monodroid. I use eclipse. I dont know about monodroid

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're looking for a way to create a custom component control that you can drop into your android project in Eclipse? Then yes its possible :)

Answer (score 2):

Yup, they're called `Fragment`s. From the documentation,

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities.

Some other ways you can tidy up your code are:

1. Inflating your layouts from xml instead of generating them programatically with Java.
2. Defining themes/styles in `res/values/styles.xml`.
3. Organizing and storing your strings in `res/value/string.xml`.
4. Making use of object composition and inheritance when appropriate.
5. Simplifying your ideas so that you don't have to write 5,000 lines of code in the first place (because 5,000 lines really is *a lot* of code...).

Comment: I didn't mean design side. I have 5000+ lines at code behind. not in xml, Java codes.

Comment: My answer was that the `.NET` equivalent (well, probably not equivalent but at least very similar) is to use `Fragment`s. Put simply, `Fragment`s are "re-usable UI components", although they serve some other useful purposes too.

Answer (score 0):

Extend one of the viewgroup classes such as LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.  You can create an xml layout with the viewgroup as the root of the layout then implement any custom behavior in the java class.